# Greater Trip and Attacks of Opportunity

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat-maneuver

When using [Greater Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-trip-combat---final), "...Whenever you successfully trip an opponent, that opponent provokes **attacks**(in plural) of opportunity."

Are these attacks of oportunity allowed just for **you** or adjacent **allies** to this opponent as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjacent allies as well.  If it meant just from you, it'd say just from you. They just provoke, which means anyone who threatens may take one.

Comment: I would say this plural here in "attacks" lefts clear what would be otherwise an ambiguous sentence. I agree, it provokes in favor of all threatening creatures.